# How to get dict value from shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I have did a curl request and get the response bellow:

```
$ curl -s http://xx.com/api
$ {"key":"value"}
```

How can I get the value directly from the request? Like this:

```
$ curl -s http://xx.com/api | XXXX
$ value
```

Comment: You should probably look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919750/parse-json-with-shell-scripting-at-linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
curl -s http://xx.com/api | sed 's/.*:"\(.*\)".*/\1/'
```